# Как текст, выходящий за границы Div, вписать в div

Tags: html, css

Мой текст должен вылезать за пределы `div`-блока cлева и справа. Так же как и на картинке ниже. За пределы экрана немного вылезают буквы `Н` и `О`.

- мой `footer`-блок не прижимается к нижней части экрана... Это происходит из-за line-height.

Как должно быть:
Серый фон - это граница (В фотошопе решил так ограничить границы моего сайта)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*Footer*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer>div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 18vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -9vw;
  background-color: rgba(146, 241, 72, 0.7);
  color: rgba(241, 72, 234, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

footer>div>span {
  font-size: 4vw;
}

footer>span {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: .68em;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  font-size: 18vw;
  margin-left: -10vw;
  margin-top: -4vw;
  /*margin-left: -12vw;*/
}

.footer_space_top {
  margin-top: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <span class="footer_space_top">УЛ. ПЯТНИЦКАЯ, ДОМ 17</span>
    <span>+7 499 722 18 19</span>
  </div>
  <span>НЕПОНЯТНО</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: Опиши нормально какого результата хочешь добиться... ни чего не понял

Comment: Запомни `top right  bottom && left` БЕЗ `position`  не работают

Comment: @Air добавил подробное объяснение.

Comment: Про bottom - я пробовал до этого position. Не помогло. А bottom забыл удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*Footer*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

footer>div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 18vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -9vw;
  background-color: rgba(146, 241, 72, 0.7);
  color: rgba(241, 72, 234, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

footer>div>span {
  font-size: 4vw;
}

footer>span {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5%;
  width: 110%;
  line-height: .68em;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  font-size: 18vw;
  margin-left: -10vw;
  margin-top: -4vw;
  /*margin-left: -12vw;*/
}

.footer_space_top {
  margin-top: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <span class="footer_space_top">УЛ. ПЯТНИЦКАЯ, ДОМ 17</span>
    <span>+7 499 722 18 19</span>
  </div>
  <span>НЕПОНЯТНО</span>
</footer>
```

Не уверен что правильно понял задачу, но вот решение) Если что подсказывайте что должно быть не так

Comment: вообще не правильно) У Вас буква "О" в слове "непонятно" создает дополнительное (лишнее) пространство справа.

Comment: Изменил, пробуйте

Comment: Да, это то, что надо!